# ¿Cómo guardar un array de inputs dinámicos en livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, component, laravel-livewire, livewire

Tengo un componente *livewire* con el cual creo un modal con inputs dinámicos, en este modal tengo un input estático y un botón para agregar mas inputs:

```
<div class="modal-body">
      <form>
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                     <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="name">Indicador: 1</label>
                          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>             
           @foreach ($orderIndicadores as $index => $orderProduct)
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                   <label for="indicador">Indicador</label>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                   <div class="input-group">
                          <input type="text" name="indicador" class="form-control me-3" required
                          wire:model="orderIndicadores.{{$index}}.indicador">                                  
                          <button wire:click.prevent="removeIndicador({{$index}})"
                           class="btn btn-danger rounded-circle">H</i></button>
                    </div>
                            
                </div>
           <div>
           @endforeach
           <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-6 text-center">
               <button wire:click.prevent="addIndicador" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle my-2">+</button>
           </div>
       </form>
</div>
```

En mi componente tengo las funciones para crear y quitar los inputs, estas funciones están vinculadas con *wire:click* dentro de la vista en sus respectivos botones.

```
public $orderIndicadores = [];
public function addIndicador()
    {
        $this->orderIndicadores[] = ['indicador' =>''];
    }
public function removeIndicador($index)
    {
        unset($this->orderIndicadores[$index]);
        $this->orderIndicadores = array_values($this->orderIndicadores);
    }
```

Esto funciona bien, en la vista me agrega y elimina los inputs dinámicamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de agregar estos inputs dinámicos quiero guardarlos, para ello en el botón guardar del modal puse un *wire:click="save"*, dentro del componente creé la función *save*, lo que se me ocurrió fue hacer un *foreach* de *$orderIndicadores* que es el array vinculado a los inputs, y dentro del *foreach* llamar al modelo *Indicadores* y guardar los campos mediante *create*.

```
public function save(){
        foreach($this->orderIndicadores as $indicador){
            Indicadores::create([
                'nombre' => $indicador,
                'proceso_vinculado' => 1
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Pero de esta forma no estoy teniendo en cuenta el input estático y de igual manera lo estoy haciendo mal ya que no me guarda los inputs dinámicos, me sale este error:

> TypeError Argument 1 passed to
> Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array,
> int given

¿Cuál es la mejor manera de guardar estos inputs dinámicos y tener en cuenta el input estático mediante un componente *livewire*?

Comment: Como es tu relación de proceso e indicador?

Comment: @JulioGuerrero un proceso puede tener muchos indicadores, pero un indicador solo le puede pertenecer a un proceso, ese 'proceso_vinculado' es el id del proceso, solo lo dejé como un 1 entero por pruebas con los inputs dinámicos.

Comment: Podrías probar con el metodo createMany de eloquent. 
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

Comment: @JulioGuerrero agregando el createMany no funciona igual.

Comment: En que linea tienes el error que te lanza?

Comment: Hiciste esto en modelo Indicadores?

protected $casts = ['nombres' => 'array'];

Answer (score 0):

Usé este ejemplo y funciona perfecto:

```
https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-livewire-dynamically-add-or-remove-input-fields
```

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/336070)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).